# Anuglar2 routing from one localhost to another localhost with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have two angular apps which I run on different localhosts of-course. I'm navigating from one localhost1 to another one with--> localhost2.

```
window.location.href="another localhost"
```

The problem is that I'm using the location hash strategy and because of that my app navigates to the component and then **comes back** to the home page of localhost2. If I remove the `{useHash: true}` then the routing works as expected.

What can I do to avoid this. I must use the `{useHash: true}` in my localhost2. Should I use something before `window.location.href`f or something after it?

Comment: Are you providing full URL like ` window.location.href = 'http://localhost:7000/';`?

Comment: Yes, full url is being provided

Comment: This should be fine then, are you setting `href` as well in Html if you are using `a`, If yes you should not ?